# How to display GUID in Kendo Grid?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I just want to display a GUID from my model in a Kendo grid in the view, but I am getting this error each time:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Guid',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.String'.

This is my grid code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.revisions)
                    .Name("RevisionsGrid")
                    .Columns(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.Bound(p => p.RevisionInfo.Id).Title("Revision ID");
                        columns.Bound(p => p.Accident.Id).Title("Accident ID")
                            .ClientTemplate("#= (Accident.Id == null) ? '' : Accident.Id.toString() #");
                        columns.Bound(p => p.RevisionInfo.RevisionDate).Title("Date Modified");
                        columns.Bound(p => p.RevisionInfo.User.Name).Title("By User");
                        columns.Command(command => command.Custom("ViewPdf").Text("View PDF").Click("getPdf"));
                    })
                    .Selectable()
                    .Pageable(p => p.PageSizes(new[] { 5, 10, 25 }))
                    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                    .Server()
                    .Model(model =>
                        {
                            model.Id(p => p.RevisionInfo.Id);
                            model.Field(p => p.Accident.Id).DefaultValue(Guid.NewGuid());
                        }))
```

The problem is with the second column which is bound to Accident.Id, a GUID type. My attempts at fixing this included adding the ClientTemplate to that column & adding a default value for it, but neither of these helped. I also tried just adding ToString() in the column definition but then I get a different error about .Bound() only taking a property access method as an argument.

Is there some place to convert the GUID to a string in order to display it here?

Comment: Just curious what is the datatype of Accident.Id in Model.revisions? Is it Guid or string? Can you try converting this property to string?

Comment: @Anil Vangari It's Guid. I'd rather not change the data model at this point because in the database it really is a Guid, and all the other models use Guids for their id properties, changing it would likely affect a lot more than just this grid.

Comment: What's wrong with Guid.NewGuid().ToString()? Ah - this is what I get for not reading your code correctly. This is one reason why I prefer separating "viewmodels" from "datamodels". Your view model could be a string while the data model is a GUID and you just provide translation code for initializing/updating between models, and everything else just works.

Comment: @SteveG your comment is actually really helpful. We do have a separate view model from what's in the data model & everything else is a string except the new entity I just added. Whoops, haha. Still new to MVC, will have to figure out a better way to represent this even though I found a work around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. In order to have the Kendo grid accept something that's not a string you need to specify a template for the column, in which you *can* call `ToString()`. I couldn't call it in binding.

```
columns.Bound(p => p.Accident.Id).Title("Accident ID")
    .Template(p => p.Accident.Id.ToString());
```